# Specification at Joel Test, What is the meaning?

Tags: testing, specifications

There are several terms at Joel Test. 
One of them is

- `Do you have a spec?`

What kind of specification does it refer to? 
Does it refer to `Software Requirements Specification (SRS)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my QA experience I can definitely sat that spec in Joel Test is condired to be kindaof functional spec:
*The most important function of a spec is to design the program. Even if you are working on code all by yourself, and you write a spec solely for your own benefit, the act of writing the spec -- describing how the program works in minute detail -- will force you to actually design the program. (c) Joel. ...
Giant reason number two is to save time communicating. When you write a spec, you only have to communicate how the program is supposed to work once.(c) Joel*

Additional details you can discover [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000036.html)
 and also [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html) (point 7).

So to add some info from my QA expirience sometimes you come across with the following situation:
Sometimes testing activities can start late after a piece of application has been already developed and to some extension I should say developed without any spec. In such situation you are uncapable of performing any testing activities as you do not know the expected behaviour of the system, which is provided by any functional spec. So this bright example shows why specs are so important in QA and dev departments collaboration)